# validator.js bootstrap works but show not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have ajax form as on modal window. I want to validate the fields and i have followed the following [tutorial](https://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/). and Add the `validator.js` script into my project.

```
 event.preventDefault();

        //$('#myOrderDetailsForm').validator();

       $('#myOrderDetailsForm').validator('validate')();
```

Here is what am seeing :
[image]

So wired .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$('#myOrderDetailsForm').validator('validate')();
```

Use following:

```
$('#myOrderDetailsForm').validator('validate'); //removed ()
```